# Selenium Chrome Driver : unable to click on Mouse hovered menu link in Chrome version 31

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

After mouse hovering to any Tab in Chrome Driver, menu options appears and suddenly menu is getting closed and hence unable to click on menu options.
I added delay after mouse hovering to the Tab, but still issue exists. Pls suggest

This scenario was working perfectly till Chrome veriosn 29, after upgrading to Chrome to 31 facing this issue.

am using Selenium with version 2.39, Chrome 31 and chrome driver executable 2.8.

Comment: There are usually other ways to click an element using Selenium, without involving mouse or keyboard. Can you provide the URL of the web-page that you are trying to automate?

Comment: web page belongs to my comapny smb application.. need to login.. if possible can you pls mention work arounds for chrome.. I tried with javascript executor.. cliking with Selenium Action class, but they are not consisitent..

Comment: I need a working example so I could give it a try. Cannot give a generic workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Try to keep the physical mouse outside the bounds of the chrome window when running the test. Initialize chrome as a window of course, not maximized. That's the default anyway I guess.